# Generate mongoid:config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm trying to generate config of mongoid.

Ruby on Rails 4,

Ruby 2.1.0

everytime i try  "rails g mongoid:config" it throw following error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/bin/rails:9:in `require': cannot load      such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rails:23:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mongoid from github for rails 4

```
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
```

Comment: Would you like to accept this answer if somehow it helped to you?) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked Mongid at [Ready For Rails 4](http://ready4rails4.net/gemfile_check/new), and got this:

[image]

`Mongoid V4.0.0` hasn't been released yet( there is only `4.0.0.alpha2V`)